# How to output Pine Script Orders to an Exchange or Broker using API

Tags: api, pine-script, tradingview-api

I've looked around and there's not much information about exporting Orders from a PineScript strategy to the exchange or broker, ideally would prefer to use Binance.
How do I connect pinescript to Binance API

Answer (score 0):

Solved, can be done with a 3rd party like capitalise.ai or 3commas.io